# JQuery autocomplete select component with multiple values

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox, multi-select

Recently I asked about JQuery autocomplete select/combobox component. However, I haven't been able to find an example where user could select multiple values. My question is now is this even possible? If not, is there anything else what would fit my needs?

Comment: The component I'm looking for is some sort of list box,

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but still comes up high on search results.
jQueryUI now has this in its autocomplete function (which operates on an `<input>` tag, not a `<select>` tag).
See https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple for a working example.
Personally, I'm looking elsewhere because I prefer to populate a `<select>` and then have it modified by javascript to an autocomplete - it makes for a safe fallback if the javascript fails.